# How to include slide out menu on every page IOS (remove back button)

Tags: ios

I am making a ios app which has a slide out menu. I followed the following tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/ without too much trouble.

However something I was left asking myself was how to include to navigation menu on every page of my application. What I mean by this is that if my menu takes me to a page, from there how would I make a link to a new page which will still have the menu. At the moment I see a back button at the top left.

Most tutorials I found stop there. I have a different controller for every page in my menu. And I use reveal view controller.

Comment: Most apps that have this style of reveal menu only have it available from the root view of each "section", see spotify etc. To try and maintain access to the menu and provide a back button will lead to a cluttered and confusing UI

Comment: I see... It wouldn't be cluttering the ui. I want to get rid of the back button completely. once I am done with a page i don't need it again. but i want to be able to access any section at any time. so that is not easily feasible?

Comment: This was designed as a very simplistic prototype which I had less than a week to implement

Comment: It is feasible look into containerView as per @Mrunal answer, or perhaps a UIPageViewController could work for you. It is still not a design pattern I would recommend, no back button = confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You would require a RootViewController which will have that top left button and other than that, entire screen will act as a container box. (empty view, let say UIView containerView)
- Add a subview in that view as per your requirement let say if you have 3 buttons in Menu then initially you should load view1 by default.
- If user selects 2nd option, then first remove all the views inside the containerView

> ```
> for (UIView *subview in containerView.subviews)
> {
>
>    [suview removeFromSuperView];
> }
>
> // then, add your new selected view
> [containerView addSubView: view2];
> ```

References:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Hope you have got what I am trying to convey.

Comment: @AnnaYelizarova Did you find this answer relative? If yes, then upvote and accept the same.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, can you please up-vote the same. :)